# Jquery Mobile page transition is laggy / Cordova app

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've created a simple persisent navbar menu in my Cordova/PhoneGap App (like here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html)

I've added slide transition effect between the pages but this transition it's very laggy on mobile and you can see huge spikes and that the view is changed.

Also, while switching between pages css is "lost" for a fraction of second and you can see all html elements arranged wierd in page.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy SIII to test the app, so a phone with decent hardware configuration.

Is this normal? Can this be fixed? Doesn't seem something which should happen.

Here's my code with two pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="search">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="menu" data-position="fixed" class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1>Search</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#search"  data-transition="none" data-icon="grid" data-prefetch="true">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#favorites" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="search" data-prefetch="true" class=" ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Favourites</a></li>                    
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
        <!-- CordovaTry references -->
    <div data-role="content">content</div>
    <div data-role="footer">foot</div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="favorites">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="menu" data-position="fixed" class="ui-header ui-bar-a ui-header-fixed slidedown">
    <h1>Favourites</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar ui-mini" role="navigation">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#search" data-transition="slide" data-icon="grid" data-prefetch="true">Search</a></li>
             <li><a href="#favorites" data-transition="none" data-icon="search" data-prefetch="true" class=" ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Favourites</a></li>       
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    <!-- CordovaTry references -->
    <div data-role="content">content</div>
    <div data-role="footer">foot</div>
```

and here are my includes

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: test in a normal desktop browser to see if the same issues

Comment: no, in the browser (desktop pc) everything is ok

Comment: Any Android below  4.4 (KitKat) will have noticeable CSS animation performance impact.

Comment: Add user-scalable=no to your meta http://www.halilibrahimkalkan.com/en/post/2013/01/07/Solution-to-flicker-problem-in-jQuery-mobile-page-transitions.aspx#comment